# Definite article and abstract concepts?

Tags: definite-article

Consider the following sentence:

> They both grew up in a rural area and dislike **the** urban life

I wonder if the sentence is yet correct without the bold *the*. If yes, will it's meaning change? I wonder how we say "I like history" instead of "I like the history", but in the example it said "they dislike the urban life"?

related: [When to use 'the' before next/previous?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/132784/when-to-use-the-before-next-previous)

Comment: in **a** rural area and dislike **(the)** urban life.  **the** is optional. They both **grew up**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo thanks, If optional, I wonder why the speaker bothered himself say it.

Comment: Because **the** underscores the idea that speaker and listener share a definition or understanding of "urban life".   If I said to someone *You know how **the** Persian thinks.* it assumes that I and they have a shared belief about people from Persia.  There is a creature "the Persian" whose attributes we agree on.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo regarding "to grow" I copied the sentence from "https://ptestudy.com/pratice/detail/?cate=35&pindex=3"  is it incorrect?

Comment: I think the speaker might actually be saying "They **have** both grown up..." but his accent is not good.  "They *are* both grown up" is definitely incorrect.

Comment: @PHPst: the link is not working.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo https://ptestudy.com/pratice/detail/?cate=35&pindex=3 And there is the voice of the sentence as well

Comment: He says "They are both grown up in **a** rural area and dislike the urban life."

Comment: He has some trouble with "rural area" but that said, a native speaker can have trouble with **rural juror**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, wouldn't the definite article convert the phrase "urban life" to the nominative, where omitting the article would make the phrase partitive?  I wonder if the difference is "I dislike every aspect of urban life" vs "I like some things, but not enough to want to be part of it."  What are your thoughts?

Comment: @JBH: The article **the** has no bearing on whether **(the) urban life** is functioning in a nominative role, and the mere omission of the article does not make it a partitive construction.  Compare **the contemplative life**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, there is no real difference between

> They both grew up in a rural area and dislike **the** urban life.
>   They both grew up in a rural area and dislike urban life.

The nuance is i the first sentence, a *particular* urban lifestyle is understood, in the second it is urban life *in general*.

> ...dislike **the** urban life *of an investment banker*.